# while starting orderer service in multihost env orderer1-org0 | panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Environment - Multihost Env(4org,1 org hosting entire raft clusters)
Followed the fabric-ca operations guide till genesis block everything went fine but while creating the docker for ordering service found the following error:

[orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 004 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
orderer1-org0 | panic: runtime error: index out of range [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zompr.png) with length 1

The below commands when executed confirm the hash for key,ca are same but doesn't match with tls-ca
openssl pkey -in hyperledger/org2/peer1/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum
openssl x509 -in hyperledger/org2/peer1/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem -pubkey -noout -outform pem | sha256sum
openssl x509 -in hyperledger/org2/peer1/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tls-orderer1-org0-7052.pem -pubkey -noout -outform pem | sha256sum

Can you help to identify in which particular step in operation guide would have caused the error so that I can rerun from that if I need to restart completely then what is the change or caution that I need to consider. Note the passwords for the ca and tls-ca for certain identities are different as per the latest operation guide hope this didn't cause the issue. Attached the docker for the orderer and screenshot of the file.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: What version of Fabric exactly are you running? Also, please prefer copy-pasting of text rather than screenshots, as it will make it much easier for those answering your question, as well as those searching for your question in the future.

Comment: Fabric version is 2.1.1, While creating organization the subjecter and issuer are different and while creating tls-ca subjecter and issuer are the same this may be causing error think so if anyone knows this please confirms

Error:
initializeServerConfig -> INFO 004 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
orderer1-org0    | panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 1
orderer1-org0    | 
orderer1-org0    | goroutine 1 [running]:

Comment: I feel the issue is with `IsCA` property of your CA certificate. It should be set to true for a organization root certificate or intermediate certificate. Assuming you are not using intermediate CAs, the `IsCA` property is missing in your root CA certificate.